# Fully executing Command Line In Java before moving on

Tags: java, web-applications, web, command-line

I am currently running a VB script file through the command line in Java. The script file converts a video from one format to another. The problem that I am having is that after executing the command line code, Java immediately moves on to the next piece of code, without the VB Script actually completing.

For e.g:

```
          try {  
              Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C C:/Users/dheerajg/Desktop/webex2.vbs");  

          } catch (IOException e) {  
              e.printStackTrace();  
          }
```

Immediately below this I have:

```
<table border="2">
      <tr>
            <td><b>You have successfully converted the file by the name of:</b>
            <%
                  out.println(saveFile);

            %>
            </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

However, I only want the second block of code to execute in my Web Application after the script has completed. Is there a way in Java where it will automatically detect when the script has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `p.waitFor();`

[look at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you consult the API? [Process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29)